# Django form not showing up

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new to django and trying to show a form in an html file and I don't see the fields .
I can see everything except the form.

Task:

> Allow the user to type a query into the search box in the sidebar to
> search for an encyclopedia entry.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    searched = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Search(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.cleaned_data["item"]
            for i in entries:
                if item in entries:
                    page = util.get_entry(item)
                    page_converted = markdowner.convert(page)
                    
                    context = {
                        'page': page_converted,
                        'title': item,
                        'form': Search()
                    }

                    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", context)
                if item.lower() in i.lower(): 
                    searched.append(i)
                    context = {
                        'searched': searched, 
                        'form': Search()
                    }
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", context)

        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {"form": form})
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
            "entries": util.list_entries(), "form":Search()
        })
```

layout.html

```
<div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
    <h2>Wiki</h2>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'index' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.item}}
    </form>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'create' %}">Create New Page</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'random' %}">Random Page</a>
    </div>
    {% block nav %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Search class

```
class Search(forms.Form):
    items = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass', 'placeholder': 'search'}))
```

Comment: Shouldn't `layout.html` be `index.html`, or is that a typo?  You are not sending 'layout.html' anythere

Comment: You should provide result as error or rendered html And **please correct indentation**

Comment: 2 different files . index.html extend layout.html

Comment: `form` is not defined when method != 'POST'

Comment: @GAEfan i add answer about it can you see my answer for edit :) and improvments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{{ form.as_p }}` or just `{{ form }}` instead of `{{ form.item }}`.

I think `item` doesn't refer to anything.

---

**Update:**

There is a typo in your `Search` form class. The field name should be `item` not `items`.

Comment: is from here  `item = form.cleaned_data["item"]`

Comment: @EdyEduard did you try what I said?

Comment: yes . form appeared but now i get a Key Error at Item `item = form.cleaned_data["item"]`

Comment: @EdyEduard Update the question and add the content of the `Search` form class. It should contain a field `item` otherwise, you'll get `KeyError` whenever you try to get it.

Comment: @EdyEduard there is an extra `s` in the field name of the `Search` form class